# How to calculate days until next occurrence?

Tags: r, dplyr

Have asked another question using a similar dataset, but different question -

I have a dataset that is a list of dates, followed by a column that either contains "R" for regular or "S" for special:

```
date <- c('01/01', '01/02', '01/03', '01/04', '01/05', '01/06', '01/07', '01/08', '01/09')

day <- c('S', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'S')

data <- data.frame(date, day)
```

It looks like this:

```
date . . . day

01/01. . . S

01/02. . . R

01/03. . . R

01/04. . . R

01/05. . . R

01/06. . . S

01/07. . . R

01/08. . . R

01/09. . . S

....
```

Now I'm trying to add a column that would indicate how many days there are until the next "special" day. So, for the shown data, it'd be 0 (01/01 is special), 4 (01/02 is 4 days away from the next special day, 01/06), 3, 2, 1, 0 (01/06 is special), etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach. You can use `cumsum` to group the days prior to a special day together, and then countdown by taking the number of days `n()` and subtract the row number `row_number()` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(day, default = first(day)) == 'S')) %>%
  mutate(days_until = n() - row_number())
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   grp [3]
  date  day     grp days_until
  <fct> <fct> <int>      <int>
1 01/01 S         1          0
2 01/02 R         2          4
3 01/03 R         2          3
4 01/04 R         2          2
5 01/05 R         2          1
6 01/06 S         2          0
7 01/07 R         3          2
8 01/08 R         3          1
9 01/09 S         3          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea via base R. Use `cumsum` to create groups when day is `S`, take the length sequence of each and replace the maximum value (that corresponds to `S`) with 0, i.e.

```
i1 <- cumsum(data$day == 'S')
data$res <- ave(i1, i1, FUN = function(i) { i2 <- seq_along(i); rev(replace(i2, max(i2), 0)) })
```

which gives,

> ```
>    date day res
> 1 01/01   S   0
> 2 01/02   R   4
> 3 01/03   R   3
> 4 01/04   R   2
> 5 01/05   R   1
> 6 01/06   S   0
> 7 01/07   R   2
> 8 01/08   R   1
> 9 01/09   S   0
> ```

Comment: Thanks as well, just saw Ben's answer first! Appreciate it